# Help with suffering baby pine tree

Tags: plant-care, tree-care, urban-gardening, pines

I was given a young pine tree some months ago.
 I placed it in a larger pot in the communal garden (so I cannot see it from my window) and hardened off during the winter. It is now outside since months, and it started growing new bright green sprouts on its branches. It is now around 45 cm tall.

One week ago I went out after one week I was home, and I went checking on the tree. I found it outside the pot, with roots exposed, laying on one side. Its leaves became crisp and started falling, and the sprouts turned pale from bright green. I don't know how long it has been laying like that.

I placed it back into the pot and started watering as soon as I feel the soil is not that dump, so I don't wait it to dry, and till I see water coming from the bottom of the pot. I don't know if it needs anything more or if I am doing things right.

Would you please let me know how I can fix it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is nothing you can do other than to keep the plant watered as necessary. If needles turn brown on any branch, whilst that  branch may  not be dead, it will only produce growth at the tip of the branch, leaving the area where needles have fallen bare. If too many branches are totally bare, you may decide its not  worth keeping the plant because it is not attractive to look at, but see how it recovers.

Comment: it is always you coming to the rescue .. I guess I will keep watering it, I don't care if it looks bad honestly, I just want it to live. What are the chances that it may just die?

Comment: Hard to say - I can't see it, can I... sorry its always me... but with this lockdown in the UK, I;'m spending a great deal (or most) of my time on the internet!

Comment: actually it was a way to say thank you! I took a picture of the tree, can it be of any help?

Comment: Yea, probably - add to the question...

Comment: done. Thank you again. the picture looks even flattering actually, somehow does not render the tired appearance of the tree, it does not show how needles became "crispy" and dry, and how just a touch makes them fall.

Comment: well they often are still green when they fall... I can see it looks a bit dry and wilty towards the top, those  needles might just drop, but if they all do, you can at least cut the tops down to live growth. Just keep it watered in the meantime, fingers crossed. Looks a bit crooked, is it planted upright in its pot?

Comment: I might have replanted it slightly slanted. I noticed it afterwards, and didn't think it is so important. Is it?

Comment: Well, yes and no - it might be wise to reposition it now, before it settles back in properly, otherwise it will continue  to grow crooked and if it survives, it;ll be more difficult to correct later on.